# Managing Big Data in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, store

I'm following an Angular2 course having a background of Sencha ExtJS framework.

My question is pretty easy : with AngularJS how do you store and interact with big data structures? In all the course when a Service was retrieving data was always small and was stored in an array.

Why did I mention ExtJS? Because it offers classes called Store to, as the name says, store data and query it, with possibility of filtering,sorting,mapping and so on.

Let's make an example :

I have the list of the airports in the world and I want to offer it in a select. Of course i will setup the service injected to the select that offers the entire list. But then:

-I want to filter it as the user go on typing

-The array containing the data is an array of objects with other properties after the name like the country or the id

Which is the approach to follow?

Comment: hi, what is preventing you from storing the data (ie. list of the airports) in the smart component on top of your application? This is the most common design I saw so far.

Comment: if the problem is related to query methods for a list of complex objects, you can use one of the most famous libraries (Lodash offers _map_, _filter_, _fold_, ...) or RxJS to work asynchronously.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. As new to Angular i needed just to understand the management.There is nothing built-in and you have to delegate to external libraries. As I was saying ExtJS was delivered with all this managements already included. What do you mean with smart component? the app.component? However thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome! the _App.component_ can be assumed as a smart one in almost all cases: it will host business logic and can retain states (like your airports' list) if needed. I've elaborated more in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, here's my answer.

In Angular 2 we have *smart components*, which hosts logic and data, and *dumb components* which are pure views, with no logic and preferably stateless.

Ideally, you could retrieve your data from the API and deliver it to your smart components either returning the whole data or exposing a stream with RxJS.

An example using [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) would be:

- A service calling the APIs and returning an [Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) with the data
- A smart component consuming the service's data, in the form of a [Subscription](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html)
- One or more dumb component in showing the data which is pushed down by the smart component (acting as a container)

At this point, your data manipulation could reside either in the service or in the smart component (it depends on what you need to transform and how).
To manipulate the data, I suggest you use [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) which offers the possibility to chain streams and [filter, aggregate, map, ...](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md) methods. It is asynchronous.

If you can go for something less complex but blocking (it depends on your requirements), I'd suggest you use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), which brings methods for collections to chain, map, filter, and aggregate data.